# Build an equivalent R request for a curl request

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, httr

I have the following `curl` request:

```
curl --request GET --header "key: value" http://urlhere
```

How can I run the request in R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `GET` function:

```
library(httr)
r <- GET("http://urlhere", add_headers(key = value))
```

`add_headers` allows you to add header data to your request.

If you use `?GET` you can see more information and options.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I tried it but I am getting Status: 401 as response to the request. Could this be some permissions issue?

Comment: Yep, 401 is unauthorized error code. More info on [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)